# How does adding/omitting lemmatization affect TF-IDF?

Tags: natural-language, tf-idf

Lemmatization has some obvious benefits in TF-IDF, e.g. it decreases the vocabulary size.

What are some other advantages, and **what are some disadvantages** to lemmatizing in the context of TF-IDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what language are you working on and on what task are you trying to solve

Lemmatization would more likely help in **topic modeling task**, as suggested on:
https://opendatagroup.github.io/data%20science/2019/03/21/preprocessing-text.html

> Topic modeling, for example, relies on the distribution of content words, the identification of which is dependent on a string match between words, which is achieved by lemmatizing their forms so that all variants are consistent across documents

Lemmatization would more likely result in less accuracy in **sentiment analysis**, as suggested on:
https://www.quora.com/Is-it-normal-to-get-better-accuracy-without-stemming-and-lemmatization-than-using-them-in-NLP-text-classification

For example, past tensed words could be judged as more negative / more likely to occur in negative sentences than present tense. The word `hated` could be more negative than `hates`.